# Adding a background image to a link?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a class, it looks like this:

```
.blueButton {
    some css goes here
}
```

Now to use the "button", I use this HTML code:

```
<a href="..." class="blueButton">link text</a>
```

This displays my button, the only thing I am missing is a background image right of the link text. I tried:

```
background: url('image url') no-repeat top right;
```

But the image did not show up ... is this the right way to do it? This is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/bSDYG/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a demo? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is preferable.

Comment: It works! But other of your 'background' porperties cover up the image. Remove them, and you will see the background. So, what do you want to recive?

Comment: I just want an image right of the button text, thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want both the image and the gradient to be backgrounds, use the following syntax:

`background: url(image-url), linear-gradient(...);`

I.e., to specify multiple backgrounds, separate their definitions with commas.

Comment: This will not get the results that an author wants. It will overlap an image on top of the gradient button. Looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You set background twice. First time, as an image. Then, as a gradient. Only the last time applies.

To have an image next to the button, you will have to have two separate elements (e.g. two spans) within your anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/opexiw/1/edit)**

```
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #98bff0), color-stop(1, #5e8dc6) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #98bff0 5%, #5e8dc6 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#98bff0', endColorstr='#5e8dc6');
background: url('http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjBC-ecGBr9x-QZ5Y7luNjiCNz3VuH1K7GeVu-rwabtLz_6QkrKVsUXfg') no-repeat center right;
background-color:#98bff0;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
display:inline-block;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:6px 8px;
text-decoration:none;
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot apply multiple backgorunds to the same element.

Your best bet would be to add a span in your link and give it the background.